# It's not possible to attach data from custom backend to Next-auth user's object

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next.js and Next-auth for authentication

I have a separate custom express api to create a custom token when user signIn with one of the oAuth provider. In this example I'm using GithubProvider

For some reason the data from the backend is not attached to the user.apiData, when i tried to access it in jwt

This is the payload from the backend server

```
{
  user: {
    id: 2,
    email: 'dragonking@hotmail.com',
    name: 'Dragonking',
    createdAt: '2023-06-08T11:23:05.329Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-06-08T11:23:05.329Z'
  },
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5TE6MjM6MDUuMzI5WiIsInVwZGF0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjMtMDYtMDhUMTE6MjM6MDUuMzI5WiJ9LCJpYXQiOjE2ODYyMjUxMDl9.HkPSXHlYYQNhFgWv-aCpH1Dv5G9XmO_wo-0tXr00208'
}
```

**This is the code**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

const options = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user, account, profile) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/v1/users", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user,
            profile,
            account,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        user.apiData = data // <--- seems like its not attaching to user.apiData
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to save user information:", error);
      }

      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      console.log("user.apiData", user.apiData)
      token.apiData = user.apiData; // <-- I'm trying to access it here but its not possible
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token; // Add custom user ID to the session
      return session;
    },
  },
  // Add any additional configuration options here
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```